# Excel default decimals

Tags: microsoft-excel

When I open a new excel file and type "7" it appears as "0.07". The column is formatted to show no decimal points

Oddly if I type "7." it appears as "7"

(The same thing occurs if I put information in an existing excel file)
I have reinstalled excel but to no avail.

Comment: Try to set cell format to `General`. Right-click `->` `Format Cells...` `->` `General` `->` `OK`.

Answer (score 0):

This is taken from [this guide](https://kb.wisc.edu/helpdesk/page.php?id=1567):

1. Open Excel.
2. This step is dependent on the version of Excel you are using:

   In Excel **2010/2013** - Go to File -> Options

   In Excel **2007** - Go to Office Button -> Excel Options
3. Select **Advanced** in the left hand column.

   [image]

   4. **Uncheck** Automatically insert a decimal point:

[image]